# Join multiple tables in Azure Data Factory to create a structure with an embedded array field?

Tags: json, sql-server, azure-data-factory, data-transform

I am trying to set up an Azure Data Factory transformation. I have a SQL Server database with three tables: Students, StudentClasses and Classes. I would like to use Azure Data Factory to read these tables and create a JSON structure. The structure is an array of Students. A Student should have a derived field which is an array of Classes. StudentClasses  is a mapping that tells which Classes were taken by a given student. It has two fields StudentId and ClassId. I think I should be able to add a derived column to Student that is an array of Classes created using the join transformation. I have gotten as far as setting up the data flows for each of the tables. However, I can't figure out how to embed the array of classes in student.
I have tried adding a derived array field to Student. However, it is not clear how to populate it with the content I desire.

I can add a derived field called class to Class with the following expression:

```
array(classID, className)
```

The end result I am looking for is:

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "studentID": 1,
      "studentName": "John Doe",
      "classes": [
        {
          "classID": "CS101-01",
          "className": "Introduction to Computer Science"
        },
        {
          "classID": "CS102-01",
          "className": "Mathematics for Computer Science"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "studentID": 2,
      "studentName": "Jane Smith",
      "classes": [
        // ... (similar structure for Jane Smith)
      ]
    }
    // ... (additional students with their respective classes)
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you joined all the three tables using join transformations and converted into single source of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array(classID, className)` expression in derived column transformation will create an array of `ClassID`, `ClassName`. But this will not create as proper key name in key:value format created. Also, this will not be in the nested format under each student. To solve this, you can give expression like `collect(@(ClassId=ClassId,ClassName=ClassName))` in the aggregate transformation. Below is the detailed approach.

- Join all the three tables using join transformations. First Join `students` and `studentsClasses` table based on the `studentid` field. Then Join the resultant table with `classes` table based on `classid` field. Then remove the duplicate columns which came as a result of join transformations using `select transformation`.

[image]

**Data Preview of select transformation after joining all three tables:**

| StudentId | StudentName | ClassId | ClassName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | CS101-01 | Introduction to Computer Science |
| 1 | John Doe | CS102-01 | Mathematics for Computer Science |
| 2 | Jane Smith | CS101-01 | Introduction to Computer Science |
| 2 | Jane Smith | CS103-01 | Data Structures and Algorithms |
| 3 | Bob Johnson | CS102-01 | Mathematics for Computer Science |
| 3 | Bob Johnson | CS104-01 | Database Systems |

- After select transformation, take the **aggregate transformation**.In aggregate settings, Add the columns `StudentId` and `StudentName` in group by fields and in aggregates, create a new column named `Classes` and give the expression as `collect(@(ClassId=ClassId,ClassName=ClassName))`

[image]

**Data preview of aggregate transformation:**

[image]

- Take another **aggregate transformation** and do not add any column in group by fields. In Aggregates, create a new column named `Students`. Give the expression as `collect(@(StudentId=StudentId,StudentName=StudentName,Classes=Classes))`

[image]

**Data preview of Aggragate2:**

[image]

**Output Json:**

```
{
  "Students": [
    {
      "StudentId": "1",
      "StudentName": "John Doe",
      "Classes": [
        {
          "ClassId": "CS101-01",
          "ClassName": "Introduction to Computer Science"
        },
        {
          "ClassId": "CS102-01",
          "ClassName": "Mathematics for Computer Science"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "StudentId": "2",
      "StudentName": "Jane Smith",
      "Classes": [
        {
          "ClassId": "CS101-01",
          "ClassName": "Introduction to Computer Science"
...........
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Clear and detailed answer. Which makes me wonder if it is best practice to leave default names like 'join1' and 'join2'. Or should we be using more descriptive names? Is there a style guide available?

Comment: I'm doing a left join so that I can show all students. How do I get the 'Classes' field to be missing if the student has no classes. I don't want to see and empty array '[{}]'.

Comment: I guess, this is not possible to do using ADF. Better to ask a new question on this, perhaps the community can help you